# How to pick a date on calendar using selenium and class text

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EGCW.png)

I tried picking a specific date "27" using selenium as below
But it keeps saying it's out of range.

Any help?

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="27"]')[0].click()
```

Comment: if you click on "enter image description here" at the top line, you'd see the website's code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calendars could be implemented in multiple ways..

And your screenshot not provides all the details, which might be valuable, but anyway.

Based on your page source example picture it looks like you're doing everything well, since the button element might be found by text.

However, there might be the case, when several buttons will be found by `'//button[text()="27"]'`, e.g.

- Some previous (future) month date is displayed in current month

  [image: List item]

  (this is some html calendar I've just found for example)
- Some dates for previous (future) months (e.g. for December 2021) are present (but not visible) in DOM, so the xpath locates some not visible and wrong element.
- Some other calendars also present on the page and affect the elements list

I suggesting here, try to find more specific xpath to be sure, other elements won't be in the list.

```py
xpath = "//td[@class='day']//button[contains(@class, 'inner')][text()='27']"
```

and add some inspection code to understand what happens:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

xpath = "//td[@class='day']//button[contains(@class, 'inner')][text()='27']"

# I suggest to add wait here
found_list = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
print('Found elements for date 27: ' + len(found_list))
for d in found_list:
    print('Element is_displayed: ' + d.is_displayed() + ', Element is_enabled: ' + d.is_enabled())

found_list[0].click()
```

In this way you'll be able at least to know what happenings and try some adjustments.

Comment: Many thanks! It did help a lot!

Comment: @GGT thanks for the feedback. Please, concider accepting the answer, if it was helpful enough, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. But do not accept, if you expected to get some better answers.